# Weird issue in TFS - Source Control Explorer not loading

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have this weird issue in one of my colleague's computer. She can connect to our TFS Server and view the projects (and tick the checkbox for them), but the Source Control Explorer doesn't load the projects.

We initially thought it was some problem with the installation but we had another person log in the computer and the Source Control Explorer loaded the projects. We then had her log in in another Visual Studio installation in another computer - one which is confirmed working - but it didn't load for her.

She can connect to the server fine and she sees the projects upon connecting so its not privileges. Its just the Source Control Explorer won't load.

Comment: Are you positive this is not a permission issue?  What groups is she in and is that the same as the groups for another user which is working? Are the others Administrators and she is not (just guessing and differences)?

Comment: I don't actually have administrative rights on our TFS, but the one who has says she has the same privileges as each and everyone of us.

Comment: Any security groups that might differ? Wonder if the command line tools will give more verbose information.

Comment: Did all of the projects can't list or just some of them? Or try to click the refersh command on the top of Source Control Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, one account works well, another can't. Most likely this is a permissions issue. Please use [TFS Permission Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft(v=vs.100).aspx) to list your  colleague's permissions of the projects.

Example: `tf permission $/Project1  /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

> **Note:** Deny trumps allow, so if a user belongs to two groups, and one
> of them has a specific permission set to deny, that user will not be
> able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong
> to a group that has that permission set to allow.
>
> Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409271.aspx)